# find sequences that are in alphabetical order

Tags: text-processing

I want to find all sequences that are in alphabetical order in txt file, without sorting.

Example: assuming the text file looks like this:

```
aedftg
wqof
abcdef
oufn
pqrs
aabcd
```

the output should be

```
abcdef
pqrs
```

also without repeating characters like `aabcd`.

Comment: What have you tried? There are lots of interesting suggestions here [Check whether letters of word are in alphabetical order](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47201/check-whether-letters-of-word-are-in-alphabetical-order)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `perl`

```bsh
$ cat ip.txt 
aedftg
aabcd
wqof
abcdef
oufn
pqrs   
   
$ perl -F -lane '$m=1; foreach (1..$#F){ $m=0 && last if $F[$_] le $F[$_-1] } print if $m' ip.txt
abcdef
pqrs
```

- Input line is split character wise into `@F` array
- If any character occurs alphabetically prior (or same character) to the character before it, the match variable `$m` is set to `0` and loop is quit immediately
- Note this solution is partially case-sensitive, `Pqrs` will match but `pQrs` will fail

If `pqrs` is changed to `pQrs` and still needs to be matched:

```bsh
$ perl -lne '(@s) = split//,tr/A-Z/a-z/r; $m=1; foreach (1..$#s){ $m=0 && last if $s[$_] le $s[$_-1] } print if $m' ip.txt 
abcdef
pQrs
```

---

Alternate solutions with `sort` and `uniq`

```bsh
# partially case sensitive
perl -MList::Util=uniq -F -lane 'print if $_ eq join "", uniq sort @F'

# case insensitive
perl -MList::Util=uniq -lne '$ip=lc; print if $ip eq join "", uniq sort split //,$ip'
```

Comment: i use this. output also give 'aabcd'. i want output without this

Comment: @Mahela.Prasad a simple change from `lt` to `le` solves it.. suggest to edit your question to reflect it as well

Answer (score 5):

One option, hard-coded for English:

```
grep -ix 'a*b*c*d*e*f*g*h*i*j*k*l*m*n*o*p*q*r*s*t*u*v*w*x*y*z*' input
```

Credit to [NinjaBearMonkey](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/47212/41769) for spelling out the idea that was germinating in my head; I modified the regex to allow for repeated characters (`aabcc`).

**Another option:**

Using `sort` to check the locale-specific collation order is a better way to go, so that you don't have to hard-code the alphabet. As [mikejonesey did](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/318669/117549), this means you have to split the line's characters onto separate lines. I've done this with a shell script (using a modern shell that supports substring expansion) to avoid the call to sed, and which also uses `sort`'s -c option to indicate if the input is already sorted or not:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
  for((i=0; i < ${#line}; i++))
  do
    printf '%s\n' "${line:i:1}"
  done | sort -c 2>/dev/null && printf '%s\n' "$line"
done
```

If `sort` finds a discrepancy, it outputs to stderr, but we only care about the return code, so I drop stderr.

A demonstration with a non-English input (the `$` characters are the shell prompts):

```
$ cat input
αβγα
αβγ
$ ./sorted2 < input
αβγ
$
```

Comment: Noting that this will match an empty line, which one could claim is vacuously sorted.

Comment: also, `-x` option to match whole line instead of using `^$`

Comment: Or inspired by [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/47209/15701), you could do something like `grep -ix "$(printf '%c*' {a..z})"`

Comment: I would love to find a locale-specific way to expand an alphabet; could have sworn I saw something from Stephane on this, but will have to keep looking.

Comment: i want use grep like your 1st answer but output without repeating characters(aabc)

Comment: Despite the fact that "aabc" is in alphabetical order?

Comment: If you only want nonrepeating letters, then do like NinjaBearMonkey and use `a?b?c?`...

Comment: first i used     find . -name "*.txt" -exec grep -ix 'a*b*c*d*e*f*g*h*i*j*k*l*m*n*o*p*q*r*s*t*u*v*w*x*y*z*' '{}' \;
but when i use ? it is not working

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, an `awk`-based solution, where the usual relation of pattern and data are swapped:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ref="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"} ref ~ $0' file.txt
```

This will interpret the lines in the file as regular expressions against which the "reference" string of sorted characters from `a` to `z` is matched. Only if there is a match (which means the string in the line is a sub-string of `a ... z`) the line will be printed.

Comment: I'd expect the OP want to match `acgz` like the accepted answer does.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas You may be right, but the OP didn't clearly specify it (and the examples only included gap-less sequences) ...

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -MPOSIX -Mopen=locale -lne '
   print unless m{(.)(.)(?(?{strcoll($1, $2) < 0})(*FAIL))}' < file
```

Would print the lines of `file` except those that contain a character that does not collate after the previous one in the user's locale.

Comment: That is a rather clever approach, but you may want to add a more in-depth explanation on the collation order; I could imagine that not many people are aware of the implications of locale here ...

Answer (score 0):

```
cat homework.txt | while read aline; do 
    stringORIG=$(echo -n "$aline" | sed 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g')
    stringABC=$(echo -n "$aline" | sed 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g' | sort)
    if [ "$stringORIG" == "$stringABC" ]; then
        echo "$aline"
    fi
done
```

.

```
abcdef
pqrs
```

ps... if you don't want to use the sort command, you can convert each char to int and have an if statement to verify the last char is less than the next...